# Is there a way to keep this character?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

At the end of chapter 9,

> Lao leaves the party due to events taking place in the story.

It's been suggested that you can max affinity to keep this character from leaving the party permanently (ie, he would rejoin after the finale), but is that true?

Comment: The walkthrough mentions a question at the end of the chapter about him being a spy or not, but it doesn't have much going for it referencing party members leaving or not.

Comment: @Frank Well, I can confirm that he leaves, just not if he can come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get this character back. However, if you complete Doug's 5th heart-to-heart, you can at least get the equipment back.